# In azure logic app extract urls from nested json string

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

I would like to create an azure logic app which saves images in sharepoint. The input file is a json string, where the url of images are nested inside. I have tried to imitate my json input string down below. The story behind it is that Tim Testmann has to take notes about a tree within an app. There are many fields which he has to fill in such as "Person", "Timestamp", and many fields where he can decide how many pictures he takes. Every image objectname, e.g. "Fotos_Apppletree", has the word "foto" or "photo" inside. Every image object contains an foto description (always in the form Photo_description_) and another object,e.g. "_1_Foto_Appletree" which contains the foto information. Every Foto object has the same properties fileId, fileName, timestamp, size and url. The input strings starts with some general properties such as "comment". The image info is nested with in parent property "data".

```
{
  "comment": null,
  "data": {
    "id": "123",
    "Person": {
      "Name": "Testmann",
      "Firstname": "Tim"
    },
    "Timestamp": "2023-03-22T20:16:04.663252+01:00",
    "Fotos_Apppletree": [
      {
        "photo_description_1": null,
        "_1_Foto_Appletree": {
          "fileId": "10",
          "fileName": "Appletree_2023_03_22_19_16_09.png",
          "timestamp": "2023-03-22T19:16:09.082243Z",
          "size": 63865,
          "url": "https://path10"
        }
      },
      {
        "photo_description_2": null,
        "_1_Foto_Appletree": {
          "fileId": "11",
          "fileName": "Appletree_2023_03_22_19_16_15.png",
          "timestamp": "2023-03-22T19:16:15.082243Z",
          "size": 63865,
          "url": "https://path11"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Photos_roots": {
      "photo_description_3": null,
      "Photo_roots": {
        "fileId": "20",
        "fileName": "Roots_2023_03_22_19_16_09.png",
        "timestamp": "2023-03-22T19:16:09.082243Z",
        "size": 63865,
        "url": "https://path20"
      }
    },
    "Fotos_leaves": {
      "photo_description_4": null,
      "_1_Foto_leaves": {
        "fileId": "30",
        "fileName": "Leaves_2023_03_22_19_16_09.png",
        "timestamp": "2023-03-22T19:16:09.082243Z",
        "size": 63865,
        "url": "https://path30"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My approach is the following: I first want to enter the "data" property with a condition, then loop over all objects containing foto or photo in their name, then looping again over all these object with the condition does not contain "photo_description" to get the objects containing the image url. I am stuck as I don't know what to enter in the yellow highlighted parts. As this is quite a specific question I have not found much help while researching. Does anyone know what to add in the yellow parts? Or are there other/better approaches to tackle the problem? I would highly appreciate any help. I already apologize for how specific the problem is and that some things are likely to be unclear. Thanks a lot in advance!

[image]

**Edit:**

Using JSON to table, how can I loop over every object? What to fill in yellow parts?
[image]

**Edit 2:**

I get an error when I want to save the logic app. Something seems to be wrong with the items()['fileName'] input at create file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you looking for as an outcome though?  Which fields are you truly interested in?  I understand that you want to upload the images, that's not too hard, but what about the other data?

Comment: @Skin For this task I am only interested in saving all the images in sharepoint. The rest of the data is stored somewhere else. To do this I want to extract the url of each image as well as its filename, so I can save the image using the filename. In the http box I use items('For_each')['propertyValue'][4]['propertyValue'] to extract the url and then in create file box I save the image as items('For_each')['propertyValue'][1]['propertyValue'].PNG

Comment: And I've tested separetly that the last parts with getting the url and saving in sharepoint works when my input json is structured simpler (without the parent "data" and without the photo descriptions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the `Advanced Data Operations` connector, I think you should look at using the `Json to Table` operation.  Here's an example ...

[image: Json to Table]

In there, if you throw a filter into the call to make sure `fileName` is not null, it'll help you to zero in on the data you're after.

This is the output ...

```
[
  {
    "id": "123",
    "Timestamp": "2023-03-22T19:16:04",
    "url": "https://path10",
    "size": 63865,
    "fileName": "Tree_2023_03_22_19_16_09.png",
    "fileId": "10",
    "Name": null,
    "Firstname": null
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "Timestamp": "2023-03-22T19:16:04",
    "url": "https://path11",
    "size": 63865,
    "fileName": "Tree_2023_03_22_19_16_15.png",
    "fileId": "11",
    "Name": null,
    "Firstname": null
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "Timestamp": "2023-03-22T19:16:04",
    "url": "https://path30",
    "size": 63865,
    "fileName": "Tree3_2023_03_22_19_16_09.png",
    "fileId": "30",
    "Name": null,
    "Firstname": null
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "Timestamp": "2023-03-22T19:16:04",
    "url": "https://path20",
    "size": 63865,
    "fileName": "Appletree_2023_03_22_19_16_09.png",
    "fileId": "20",
    "Name": null,
    "Firstname": null
  }
]
```

From there, you can loop over each file and do what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That approach seems very promising. I am struggling now how to loop over every object of the new output. I've edited my question and attached a screenshot. Would you know what to fill in the yellow parts?

Comment: Firstly, using the `Body` output of the `Json to Table` result is correct for the `For Each` loop.  Within the loop itself, simply refer to the item and the relevant property by using this syntax in an expression ... `item()['url']` ... if you want other properties, just change out `url` for another property.  Make sense?

Comment: You haven’t followed my instructions. Your expression is wrong, look at my comment again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help!! It works. At first it threw me an error but with item(For_each)['url'] it worked.

Comment: oh I see it now with item and items

Comment: Hello, I apologize for bringing this back up again. I am now not allowed to use the advanced data operations toolbox anymore. Would you know of a way to extract the urls without it and just by parsing the json? Thanks a lot already in advance!!

Comment: It’s dynamic JSON so no, sorry, I don’t have an another answer for you. Why are you not allowed to use that connector?

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer! I can't use it at the moment as advanced data operations requires a subscription. Currently I am running into the error: "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription." Getting the subscription is taking longer than thought and it is rather urgent that it works.

Comment: Yeah, but you can get one, easily, and it's cheap, REALLY cheap ... https://www.statesolutions.com.au/pricing/ ... why is it taking a long time to get the subscription?  You just pay for it and I'm sure they'll send you a key almost instantaneously.  I've got one myself and as soon as you pay, the key comes through within a minute or so.

Comment: Okay good to know, then I'll wait for it! It's because I can't get the subscription myself as it's not only for my account.

Comment: Sorry Anna but what do you mean by "then I'll wait for it! It's because I can't get the subscription myself as it's not only for my account."?